# C++ class and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, class

I would like to ask if my code is safe - does not have any unintended behaviour.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

class Test {

private:
char something[20];

public:
Test(){
    strcpy(something,"Hello world!");
}
~Test() {
    printf("Destructor\n");
    }
operator char*() {
       return something;
    }
};

int main(){
    printf ("%s\n",(char*)Test());
    
    printf("End of main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It shows me

```
Hello world!
Destructor
End of main
```

but will it be always? Including different compilers. Is the object always destructed after printf function? And is this code safe?

Comment: I would implement operator<<() and use c++ iostreams instead of printf

Comment: Your code can be made safer by using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Arrays can underflow or overflow.  Also, undefined behavior may happen if the terminating nul character is missing.

Comment: You don't need to overload `operator char *`.  Use a getter.  Also, consider whether you want to return a regular pointer (so that users can modify the string) or a pointer to constant data, so users can't modify the string.

Comment: printf is only an example. Imagine any other function that takes char*.

Comment: You should test the length of any text before the text is copied into your array (account for the terminating nul character).  Capacity of the array can change and some propagations of the change may be skipped. :-(

Comment: If you need a `char *`, see `std::string::c_str()` and `std::string::data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks rather odd, but I see nothing undefined in it.

At least instead of the c-style cast you should use a `static_cast`:

```
printf ("%s\n",static_cast<char*>(Test()));
```

> It shows [...] but will it be always?

Yes.

> Is the object always destructed after printf function?

Yes.

> And is this code safe?

No. It is brittle and a small change during refactoring can cause huge problems. For example using the wrong format string with `printf` can easily be done. Overflowing the `something` member is simple. Non explicit conversions can cause confusing bugs in places where you do not expect them.

A "safer" version is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test {
    std::string something;
    public:
    Test() : something("Hello World") {}
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "destructor\n";
    }
    std::string get_something() {
        return something;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::cout << Test().get_something();
    std::cout << "End of main\n";
}
```

And perhaps consider to provide an output operator overload so that you can write `std::cout << Test();` directly to print `something` on the screen.

Comment: It's debatable whether the conversion operator should return a reference or not. You can argue it either way.

Comment: IMHO, the `operator` should be replaced by a getter method.  I don't see much code where the `operator` is overloaded like this.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I only use non-explicit conversions for very rare special cases. Will fix that.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux I managed to avoid that debate by proposing to not use the conversion ;)

Comment: Thanks, this answer my question